# Is a very simple authentication API a security issue compared to OAuth?

Tags: api, security, authentication, oauth

Two companies.

1. **MegaSocialPlatform**
2. **CorporateCompany**.

These companies have a trusted relationship with each other.

**CorporateCompany** wants that their employees can reuse their current login credentials of CorporateCompany.com on **MegaSocialPlatform**, so that their employees don't have to make another account.

**CorporateCompany** has a limited amount of development power and they don't have any fully fledged OAuth service implemented.

Would it be sufficient if they make an API where you can just post an email / password combination, and if it's right it returns some JSON with the CorporatyCompany unique ID, email and name in there?

This ID could then be used to authenticate the user the **MegaSocialPlatform**, and link it to a MegaSocialPlatform ID.

Of course the classical systems like preventing hackers from trying more than 20 passwords are still in place.

Would there be any security issues? What other problems might arise?

Comment: Who is generating the ID? Why would MegaSocialPlatform trust this? How do you prevent falsification and theft of this token? There's too much missing in this design to call it anywhere near secure or complete.

Comment: I've updated the question. In a way MegaSocialPlatform only would need the (serverside) authentication of the email and the password. The rest of the authentication/cookie process would be exactly the same as normal email/password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could implemented this way if both parties agree but the downsides are:

- the MegaSocialPlatform would "see" the CorporateCompany credentials for every user, so CorporateCompany must have a high degree of trust in MegaSocialPlatform not to store or abuse their users' credentials - avoiding this is exactly the purpose of OAuth
- users would not experience single-signon but they would have to type in their credentials over and over again when using MegaSocialPlatform, also across different platforms (e.g. browser and native app)
- both parties would need to agree on the representation of user information in the JSON object - using a standard such as OpenID Connect (largely) avoids those pairwise agreements)

Note that CorporateCompany does not have to build an OAuth server from scratch, they can just use an existing implementation and configure it to their needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Question about point 1: why would that be necessary? In a way MegaSocialPlatform could link the CorporateCompanyId to their own Db ID and store that in a cookie right? Same as they would have entered their credentials manually.

Comment: To get the MegaSocialPlatform cookie in the (right) users` browser you'll need to authenticate the user against MegaSocialPlatform.

Comment: Sorry I meant point 2 in the previous question. About the real point 1: isn't it more the question if the **end user** trusts MegaSocialPlatform? I.e. what would prevent MegaSocialPlatform right now from serving a dialog that is 100% similar to Facebook (except the url in the adressbar) that logs their Facebook email/password? Most likely that would still trap 95% of the users.

Comment: Just to be clear btw: I don't want to challenge your points, I just want to grasp this really really good :)

Comment: about your question on point 2: true, but a cookie with credentials in it should not survive browser/machine restarts, at least in secure environments

Comment: about your comment on point 3: yes, it would trap careless users but you could aim to satisfy users that do care and would have no other option; you are surely right about the user trusting MegaSocialPlatorm, but in enterprise settings there's also the IT security policy that comes in to play

Answer (score 1):

You do not say it explicitly, but I assume that the API generating the JSON (token) would run inside CorporateCompany and authenticate the user against CorporateCompany's credential store. What you describe is basically a Security Token Service ([STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token_service)).

However, in order for MegaSocialPlatform to use this token, it needs to know that was issued by an entity it trusts.  This is where [digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) come into play. A real STS will sign the token with its private key. The consuming service is configured with the public key of the STS and is therefore able to verify that the token was issued by a trusted STS.

Security tokens usually contain more information. The date/time from which they are valid and date/time after which they are no longer valid. They also contain an audience- or relying party identifier to indicate who the token is meant for, to prevent the use of a token issued for another service with MegaSocialPlatform.

Obviously all the communication between client - STS and client - MegaSocialPlatform must be done over encrypted communication channels (https) as bearer tokens are susceptible to theft.

Creating secure solutions is not trivial. You should therefore avoid implementing your own and use standard protocols and libraries or frameworks from reputable origin. 
You might want to look at the [JWT token](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/concepts/understanding-jwt.html) for more information on security tokens in JSON format.